# How to input another variable into scipy optimize function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Please ignore the messiness, still a noob at this.
Basically, I have a function:

```
def bw(Q,T):
  F = -Tc * Q**2 + T*((1+Q)*np.log(1+Q) + (1-Q)*np.log(1-Q))
  return F
```

And I need to find the minimum of this at various T's

```
Tc = 1
n = 200
T1 = 0.5
T2 = 1.2
Tt = np.linspace(T1,T2,n)
Qe = np.ndarray((1,n))
Q0 = 0.9

for i in range(n):
  T = Tt[i]
  res = minimize(bw,Q0,method='nelder-mead', options={'xatol': 1e-8})
```

With this, it says it's missing a positional argument T, but then:

```
res = minimize(bw(T),Q0,method='nelder-mead', options={'xatol': 1e-8})
res = minimize(bw(Q,T),Q0,method='nelder-mead', options={'xatol': 1e-8})
res = minimize(bw(,T),Q0,method='nelder-mead', options={'xatol': 1e-8})
```

I tried these and they don't work. Then, I tried:

```
res = minimize(bw,T,Q0,method='nelder-mead', options={'xatol': 1e-8})
```

The values I get are wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last attempt is correct, you just mixed up `Q` and `T`. It should be:

```
 res = minimize(bw,Q0,T,method='nelder-mead', options={'xatol': 1e-8})
```

Comment: One other noob tip. If you are having trouble with a new function, try to eliminate any complexity you can. For example, instead of testing the full equation, you could test something simpler like `F=Q*T`. That way only the code is tricky, not the math too.